# How to retrieve using the Client code the Access Token generated on the Server-side?

Tags: java, android, twilio

Looking at the [Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens) it seems that "you create [Access Tokens] on your server to verify a user’s identity and grant access to client API features."

Here, Twilio provides a few different ways to programmatically create Access Tokens on the Server side - it looks pretty straight forward.

I am developing an Android app-to-app calling feature and for this I've have been using the [Android quickstart-project](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android#quickstart) to go about it. However, for this code, the implementation and execution are done by copying and pasting Access Tokens generated through either the Twilio Console or Twilio-CLI commands.

Say we have our Server set up, a TwiML app and its associated URL, what would be the simplest and most straight-forward way to generate but then retrieve the access token from the Server to the Client app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you would like to access Twilio API using an access token. In that case, you should have a backend server that stores the access token because you shouldn't store such tokens in the client-side (android app). Your app would send request to your backend which would then use the access code to access the api and forward you the result back.

Comment: This is correct. For further detail, in the quickstart @D-I-S-C linked to, there is a [token server that is deployed to Twilio Functions](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android#3-use-twilio-cli-to-deploy-access-token-and-twiml-application-to-twilio-serverless) that provides tokens for the application. If you'd prefer to run your own server there are other examples, like this [Java server](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-java).